# Play! framework and log4j, changing level for specifc package to FATAL

Tags: log4j, playframework

I'm in the process of writing an application that uses the WS object to make HTTP requests. However when making them (deliberately to a service that does not run) , I get a message from the inner Play! code:

```
15:06:29,613 ERROR ~ java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused to http://127.0.0.1:9091/
```

I traced this back to WSAsync.get() (https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/ws/WSAsync.java#L199):

```
    public HttpResponse get() {
        this.type = "GET";
        sign();
        try {
            return new HttpAsyncResponse(prepare(prepareGet()).execute().get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e.toString());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

As this message is non-informational in my use case, I'd not like to show this error, so I decided to add a directive to my log4j.properties and restart the concerning application (Play! does not automatically reload it):

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, Rolling
log4j.logger.play=INFO
log4j.logger.play.libs.ws=FATAL
log4j.appender.Rolling=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Rolling.File=logs/play-as.log
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.Rolling.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Rolling.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m%n
```

However I still receive the messages in my logs. I don't really understand because it should run in the same classpath. Any guesses on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play always log under one category "play". They use always [Logger...](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/Logger.java), so your approach can't work. There was some discussion about this issue, but the developer of play prefer only one category for simplicity.

Comment: Then I really hope they remove the log statement for get() as it's not present in the other methods, like post() put() etc. See https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1337-wsasync-outputs-logging-for-get-while-it-should-probably-not I can make a pull request, but I'm not really sure what their attitude is towards this issue. Currently it's very inconsistent and I'd like the logging to be removed, as I believe it's really up to the application, what to log and what not.

Comment: I think a pull request is always useful, even in such trivial case. How ever I guess that they at the moment are in holidays. Furthermore I assume the main focus is play 2.0. If the bug is annoying you, I would recommend to build your own version. Which is really easy.

Comment: Yes I have my own version currently as a test, problem is that I must rely on the provided play installation for this application. So I will probably making a pull request tomorrow.

Comment: They have merged my pull request, so should be fine in 1.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
log4j.debug = TRUE
```

That enables debugging for log4j: You'll see which options are parsed. If you don't see anything, then the properties aren't loaded. Maybe there is a typo or the file is in the wrong place.

Note: You can specify the class name as well to avoid to suppress too much (i.e. `log4j.logger.play.libs.ws.WSAsync=FATAL`)

Also note: You should really use the XML version to configure; using properties is so error prone...

Comment: log4j: Category play.libs.ws set to FATAL

Comment: Then, I have three options: 1. This is logged before log4j is configured (unlikely; you would have spotted this). 2. Someone resets the logger after the config is read, 3. The class is loaded in a different classloader which sees another log4j config.